# Splitting strings using sscanf using matlab

Tags: string, matlab, scanf

I've been trying to reformat an array I have with file names in the format `SIM1_T-1-0.000010.cas.gz` into the individual parts: `SIM1_T-1-`, `0.000010` and `.cas.gz` but I haven't been having much success, any suggestions?

The couple of lines I've been trying:

```
for i = 1:length(casFiles)
    casNames(i,:) = sscanf(casFiles{i,1}, '%s');
end
```

Comment: Is it a cell array, or char array (char matrix)?

Comment: I didn't just try %s by the way, I've tried a few ways of having that, that's just my last go...
It's a cell array, I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this with a regexp:

```
>> tokens = regexp('SIM1_T-1-0.000010.cas.gz', '(.*-[^-]*-)([0-9]\.[0-9]*)(.*)', 'tokens', 'once')

tokens = 

    'SIM1_T-1-'    '0.000010'    '.cas.gz'
```

In my experience, the `sscanf` function will not work with a mix of numeric and alphanumeric data.

Comment: Thanks very much, preferred this one as it was a little shorter

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you have a single string (you don't specify which type of array you have; anyway you can always loop over all strings), and that the spliting pattern is to define the second part as "some digits - decimal point - dome digits".

```
str = 'SIM1_T-1-0.000010.cas.gz'; %// string to be split    
pattern = '\d+\.\d+'; %// pattern for central (second) part

part13 = regexp(str, pattern, 'split');
part2 = regexp(str, '\d+\.\d+', 'match');

part1 = part13{1};
part2 = part2{1} ;
part3 = part13{2};
```

Result:

```
>> part1
part1 =
SIM1_T-1-

>> part2
part2 = 
0.000010

>> part3
part3 =
.cas.gz
```